# Origins of "the weak are meat, and the strong do eat"

Tags: etymology, expressions

In the movie [Cloud Atlas](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1371111/), Tom Hanks' earliest character ('Henry Goose') and Hugo Weaving's latest character ('Georgie') use the phrase

> The weak are meat, and the strong do eat

Now, I don't think that's actually quoted from anywhere else, but I was wondering if it was based on / inspired by similar phrases, maxims or utterances from older, more established sources - literary, religious, legal or political.

Comment: That's pretty disgusting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, this line of dialogue **is** quoted from somewhere else. It is the English translation of the following [Japanese four-character idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_proverbs):

> 弱肉強食
>
> jaku niku kyō shoku

English translation:

> The weak are meat; the strong do eat.

Meaning:

> Survival of the fittest.

---

Edit:

This is in response to OP's request for more information regarding the origin of this Japanese four-character idiom.

It is based on a similar [Chinese expression](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BC%B1%E8%82%89%E5%BC%B7%E9%A3%9F), which has the same meaning:

> 弱肉强食

The source is [Han Yu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_Yu), a precursor of Neo-Confucianism, essayist, and poet from the Tang dynasty who was born in 768.

([Wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BC%B1%E8%82%89%E5%BC%B7%E9%A3%9F))

([Goo Dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/idiom/%E5%BC%B1%E8%82%89%E5%BC%B7%E9%A3%9F/m0u/))

([Hatena Dictionary](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%BC%E5%C6%F9%B6%AF%BF%A9))

Comment: Can you say something about the origin of this proverb, then? Who coined it or where / in what circumstances was it coined?

Comment: And indeed, it doesn't work syntactically in Japanese, though I believe it does as Chinese. But then proverbs are sometimes syntactically questionable in any language.

Answer (score 2):

Greek historian Thucydides said something similar: "The strong do what they do can and the weak suffer what they must."

Comment: Can you give a more specific reference?

Comment: The quotation appears in the 1874 Richard Crawley translation of Book V of _History of the Peloponnesian War_, in the famous [Melian dialogue](https://books.google.com/books?id=_XwJAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA394&dq=%22the+strong%22+%22the+Weak%22+Peloponnesian&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjar8ONlPTsAhUUuZ4KHQwDBGcQ6AEwBnoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20strong%22%20%22the%20Weak%22%20Peloponnesian&f=false): "... since you know as well as we do, that right, as the world goes, is only in question between equals in power, while **the strong do what they can and the weak suffer what they must**."

Answer (score 1):

In Arabic the phrase is as thus: "The Strong Eats The Weak."
القوي ياكل الضعيف
The literal translation of "Survival of the Fittest" is "البقاء للأصلح"

However, this does not illustrate the true meaning of the original phrase in Arabic. As the comparison is not evident between the strong and the weak with act of "Eating".

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is this phrase used in classic Arabic sources? Literary, political, religious?

Answer (score 0):

This is translated from the Chinese idiom:  "弱肉强食"

Chinese PinYin: ruò ròu qiáng shí
Chinese prounciation (注音)ㄖㄨㄛˋ ㄖㄡˋ ㄑㄧㄤˊ ㄕㄧˊ

It has its origin from a series of text called "送浮屠文暢师序".
It was composed in Tang Dynasty (year 803) by a poet, Tang Han Yu (唐·韩愈).

The original idiom is: 弱之肉，强之食。

Comment: 1. What is the context for the use of this idiom in Chinese? 2. What is the literal translation of the Chinese idiom into English? 3. You seem to mention two different idioms.